# How to disable one field by filling a value in another field in a MS access for

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have created a pharmacy database table. In addition to other fields, I have three fields: 'TypeTxn' (Text field) with Receipt, Issue and Loan Issue as three options in a drop down menu, Qty_R and Qty_I (both number fields depicting quantity received and issued). I want, that when TypeTxn is being filled and if 'Receipt' is selected by the user, the Qty_I field should get disabled and when Issue is selected, the Qty_R field should get disabled, i.e. one should not be able to fill data in that field. My knowledge about coding is almost nil. I have tried this code, but it does not work. Can someone help me to create the above mentioned operation in the MS Access Form?

```
Private Sub TxnType_AfterUpdate()
'  by default enable two fields Qty_R/Qty_I
Me.Qty_R.Enabled = True
Me.Qty_I.Enabled = True

'  test the value entered by user in TxnType field and hide fields as required
Select Case Me.TxnType
    Case "Receipt"
        ' if the user has entered Receipt, lock field Qty_I
        Me.Qty_I.Enabled = False
    Case "Issue", "LoanIssue"
        '   If the user has entered Issue, LoanIssue lock field Qty_R
        Me.Qty_R.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have code so what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing. Suggest you explore Conditional Formatting instead of VBA for this specific situation. But if both quantity fields cannot have a value, why even have 2 fields? TxnType identifies the type of transaction so having quantity fields for different transaction types is redundant.

Comment: Add `End Select` at the end of your `Select Case` statement block. [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is simple. It would definitively help.